# Find the value of $\sin(90-a)$

Tags: trigonometry

I was wondering if anyone here knows how to find the value of $\sin (90 - a)$ using a right-angled triangle. I can find the value using $\sin (a - b)$ but that's too lengthy and the value comes something like $\cos a$... the following might be helpful, but I'm not sure how.

[link 1](http://www.mathcentre.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/mc-ty-trigratios-2009-1.pdf)
[link 2](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100204163346AAWzkbN)

Comment: $sin(a-b)$ is the way to go, then use your knowledge of $\cos a$ and $\sin a$ when $a=90$.

Comment: And notice that it's $90$ [degrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_%28angle%29). Angles are usually measured in [radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) in mathematics (and also on computers or handhelds, is case you are also doing numeric experiments).

Answer (score 6):

There is a reason why we don't call the ratio $\dfrac{ADJACENT}{HYPOTENUSE}$ the HORIZONTALUS. It is because both of the non-right angles of a right triangle are related to each other, as they are called *complimentary angles*. Instead we call said ratio the $COSINE$, as an abbreviation of the COMPLIMENTS SINE. Suppose a right triangle has angles $\theta$, $\theta^\prime$ and $90^\circ$, then clearly $\theta+\theta^\prime$ must equal $90^\circ$ (because the sum of the angles of a triangle must be $180^\circ$). Both $\theta$ and $\theta^\prime$ share the same hypotenuse, but note that the side that is opposite $\theta$ is adjacent to $\theta^\prime$, and vice versa (see diagram).

[image]

Therefore the following relationships must hold.
$$\sin\theta^\prime =\dfrac{a}{c}=\cos\theta$$
$$\sec\theta^\prime =\dfrac{c}{b}= \csc\theta$$
$$\tan\theta^\prime =\dfrac{a}{b}= \cot\theta$$
But substituting $90^\circ-\theta$ for $\theta^\prime$ we have
$$\sin (90^\circ-\theta) = \cos\theta$$
$$\sec (90^\circ-\theta) = \csc\theta$$
$$\tan (90^\circ-\theta) = \cot\theta$$

Comment: Try Googling "triangular function"... then try Googling "circular function". Do you know why we always begin trigonometry with triangles and Satanic chants like "SOHCAHTOA"? I have no idea!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Think of a right angled triangle with angles 90, a and 90-a then use soh cah toa stuff and see what you get.

Comment: how do i use that.. idk any of the sides of the triangle...

Comment: Because if you let the hypotenuse be C the side adjacent to angle a be A and the side adjacent to angle 90-a be B you have sin(90-a)= A/C and cos(a)=A/C by trigonometric ratios.

Comment: therefore sin(90-a)=cos(a)... i get it now.. thanks... is this the simplest way there is... or is there anything simpler than that..? and how about sin(180-a) or cos(180)?

Comment: you can also do it by considering the unit circle. Sin(180-a) is not equal to cos(180). Perhaps you mean sin(180-x)=sin(x) This is true by the unit circle or you can use the fact that sin(a-b) =sin(a)cos(b)-cos(a) sin (b) so sin (180-x) = sin 180 cos(-x) - cos(180) sin (-x)= 0 - - -1 *sin (-x)= sin (x)

Comment: you wouldn't mind if i ask you how to use the unit circle to solve that... thanks again...

Comment: To do that i would need pictures all lots of words - this is easier http://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/Trigonometry-basics/Trig-identities.lesson

Answer (score 1):

Using the **unit circle**:

Draw a unit circle with a dot at $90^\circ$. Now see if the value of the sine varies as the dot moves $a$ clockwise ($90^\circ-a$) and $a$ counterclockwise $(90^\circ+a)$.